# find the parent tag of the given text from its position in html string

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am using Python to manipulate the HTML string. I want to 
find the parent tag from the given text(start & end offset of text are known) in html string.

e.g  consider the following html string

```
<html><body><span id="1234">The Dormouse's story</span><body></head>
```

input is offset (33,43) i.e. string 'Dormouse's' and the parent tag is `<span id="1234">`

Comment: Where are your python codes?

Comment: And the solution you have tried which is not working? After all, StackOverflow is not here to write your code for you. The community is here to help with overcoming problems.

Answer (score 1):

Right off the top of my head here, since you have the offset (which I think you may have to tweak because I had to use (28,48)),

1. Create a substring based on the offset.
2. Split the full html string using `split()` using the offset string as a delimiter.
3. Take the first substring created by the split and split that with `>`.
4. The second to last substring from that list of substrings is your parent tag (because the split list will return an empty string if the delimiter is at the end of the string you're splitting):

   ```
    html_string = '<html><body><span id="1234">The Dormouse\'s story</span><body></head>'
    offset_string = html_string[28:48]
    tags_together = html_string.split(offset_string)[0]
    list_of_tags = tags_together.split('>')
    parent_tag = list_of_tags[len(list_of_tags)-2]
   ```

Note you will be missing a '>' so you will have to add that back if necessary.

```
parent_tag = parent_tag + ">"
```

Also, the reason why I put the `html_string` in single quotes is because you have double quotes in there already.

This is gross and a little brutish but it should get the job done. [I am sure there exists a python library out there that can do this kind of task for you. You just need to look hard enough!](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

I recommend opening up a python shell and printing out each variable after you create it so that you can see what `split()` does. [Here are some docs for that!](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

Now that I think about it, using regex with your known offset could get you the tags too...